# Record name in a post with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, chatter

Maybe is a stupid question, but how can I setup an immediate action in the process builder where I want to post in the chatter a message like this one

> A new British Shorthair cat has arrived at Muenzpraeger's Home for Wayward Cats! His Name is {NameOfTheCat}

Specifically I want to a display the name of the record that I am updating, that is the name of the record and *{NameOfTheCat}* that I used above.

What I want to do is to add a post in a chatter group when a record is updated, I tried to use `[Cat__c].Name` put it does not work at all...

Comment: I think we need a little more information, which feed do you expect the post to appear in? The feed of the changed record? A group? all followers? etc. Additionally, what have you tried so far? The process builder post to chatter function is pretty powerful and intuitive should be easy to figure out if you give it a try. Otherwise, you can post screenshots of your efforts and we can help.

Comment: You're right! I will add all the information

Comment: I've just solved it, ita was a stupid question indeed, I had to use {![Cat__c].Name]}